# No such file or directory Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, xcode

I am getting the following error:

```
/Users/avivelkayam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-evucwwryclirvdbauuppyncmdfyp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/TrendyPalCustomer.build/Debug-iphoneos/ProjectName.build/Script-F4E471CC20FB2640005A6092.sh: line 2: /Users/avivelkayam/TrendyPal: No such file or directory
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I tried remove and reinstall cocoa pods but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try and clean derived data? You can find it in Preference -> Location -> Derived Data and then delete the folder prefixed with your app name.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it had something to do with **Podfile** and **UITest** dependencies, after I removed **UITests** pods the problem was solved.

Here is the problematic **Podfile**:

```
target 'YourApp' do
use_frameworks!
inhibit_all_warnings!

  # Pods for YourApp
    pod 'Whathever'

  target 'YourAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'YourAppUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

and here is the fixed one:

```
target 'YourApp' do
use_frameworks!
inhibit_all_warnings!

  # Pods for YourApp
    pod 'Whathever'

  target 'YourAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

target 'YourAppUITests'
```

Then run `pod install` again