# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code - No such file or directory

Tags: xcode, xcode10

Every time I try to run my iOS app on Xcode 10, it fails and gives me the error "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code"

The full error description is:

bash: /Users/Noah 1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WeatherSando-dszhaqymmhxfptfiymvnuvshlbtb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WeatherSando.app/Frameworks/AerisCore.framework/strip-frameworks.sh: No such file or directory
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

I removed all AerisWeather CocoaPods from my project, what is wrong?

Comment: It sounds as if your target still has a build phase that references the framework you removed.  Look at the "Build Phases" section of your project settings.

Comment: That did it Phillip Mills, there was one sneaky framework reference in the Run Script section of Build Phases. Thanks.

Comment: Try this if Phillip Mills solution didn't work for you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55590727/8738937

Comment: Run Script on old projects will put you in a spin.  Thanks Phillip, revisiting an old project with a Fabric run script.  Check the below answer from @Robert Desler for more details.

Answer (score 35):

For me worked what @Phillip Mills suggested. Build phase references the framework which has been removed.

In my case I removed manually embedded framework which I replaced with CocoaPod dependency. I needed script which there was previouly no longer but I didn't remove it.

---

So, look to **Build Phases** for your target and remove **Run script**

[image]

Comment: If you are revisiting an old project you might want to spend a moment and check this solution.  This was it for me. 3 year old project with Fabric run script.  Thanks Robert.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I had wrong project folder name. Project folder name shouldn't include the **space**

Comment: This is a highly underrated answer!

That was (almost) exactly my problem!
RN project was inside **grandparent folder** containing a space in folder name. I disregarded this answer since my project folder did not include spaces. x)
This answer also helped:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67289307/12322350
Thank you both!

Comment: Worked fine for me! I just relocated the project folder to the desktop and boom, it worked like magic after wasting a full day on this.

Comment: The perfect answer!

Answer (score 0):

For me it was upgrading Plaid from 1.0.0 to 3.0.0.  They have a `Build Phase` to strip the iOS Simulator part from the framework.  I had to remove that for it work.  Details found here:

https://plaid.com/docs/link/ios/ios-v2-migration/

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this error by removing the spaces in the folder name, inside which this project was set up.
After removing space, it worked

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers.

Answer (score -2):

Upgrade your flutter sdk to higher version and make sure that your android studio version is above 4.0