# Facing issue when simpling runing the build and not pressing cleaning issue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift-custom-framework

I have created a custom framework and made the framework universal-framework for simulator and iphone using following code

```
echo "project"
#open "${PROJECT_DIR}"
if [ "true" == ${ALREADYINVOKED:-false} ]
then
echo "RECURSION: Detected, stopping"
else
export ALREADYINVOKED="true"

UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iosuniversal

# make sure the output directory exists
mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}"

# Step 1. Build Device and Simulator versions
echo "iphone"
xcodebuild -workspace ${PROJECT_NAME}.xcworkspace -scheme ${PROJECT_NAME} -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -UseModernBuildSystem=NO clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator 2>&1

xcodebuild -workspace ${PROJECT_NAME}.xcworkspace -scheme ${PROJECT_NAME} -sdk iphoneos -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -UseModernBuildSystem=NO clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos 2>&1


## Step 2. Copy the framework structure (from iphoneos build) to the universal folder
echo "universal"
cp -R "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/"

# Step 3. Copy Swift modules from iphonesimulator build (if it exists) to the copied framework directory
echo "iphone simulator path"
SIMULATOR_SWIFT_MODULES_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/Modules/${PROJECT_NAME}.swiftmodule/."
if [ -d "${SIMULATOR_SWIFT_MODULES_DIR}" ]; then
cp -R "${SIMULATOR_SWIFT_MODULES_DIR}" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/Modules/${PROJECT_NAME}.swiftmodule"
fi

# Step 4. Create universal binary file using lipo and place the combined executable in the copied framework directory
echo "lipo create"
lipo -create -output "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}"
# Step 5. Convenience step to copy the framework to the project's directory
cp -R "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework" "${PROJECT_DIR}"
# Step 6. Convenience step to open the project's directory in Finder
open "${PROJECT_DIR}"
echo "end"

fi
```

Removing the unwanted architecture in application when installing it in device by using following script

```
# This script loops through the frameworks embedded in the application and
# removes unused architectures.
find "$APP_PATH" -name '*.framework' -type d | while read -r FRAMEWORK
do
FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME=$(defaults read "$FRAMEWORK/Info.plist" CFBundleExecutable)
FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH="$FRAMEWORK/$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
echo "Executable is $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

EXTRACTED_ARCHS=()

for ARCH in $ARCHS
do
echo "Extracting $ARCH from $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
lipo -extract "$ARCH" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH"
EXTRACTED_ARCHS+=("$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH")
done

echo "Merging extracted architectures: ${ARCHS}"
lipo -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" -create "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"
rm "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"

echo "Replacing original executable with thinned version"
rm "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
mv "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

done
```

issue which i am facing is the code is getting work only when i clean and build in application. if i simply build or run application without cleaning then it gives me following errors

Lipo: input file must be a fat file when the -extract option is specified
Lipo: can't open input file:frameworks-arm64(No such file or directory)
Rm: frameworks-arm64(No such file or directory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to **remove Run-Script** which contains this framework related script from **build phases** in the project and check is it working or not?

I faced the same issue for one of the projects and it worked for me.

[image]

Also, you can refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54448710/command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code-no-such-file-or-d).