# How can I launch my app on iOS after an error: PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]

Tags: git, react-native, gitlab

My app works when I download her from my repository but I can't work with the other dev.

When I git clone my app from GitLab, I have to `npm install`, then `cd ios`, `pod install`.

When I do that I have this warning:

```
[!] [Xcodeproj] Generated duplicate UUIDs:

PBXBuildFile -- Pods.xcodeproj/targets/buildConfigurationList:buildConfigurations:baseConfigurationReference:|,buildSettings:|,displayName:|,isa:|,name:|,,baseConfigurationReference:|,buildSettings:|,displayName:|,isa:|,name:|,,defaultConfigurationIsVisible:0,defaultConfigurationName:Release,displayName:ConfigurationList,isa:XCConfigurationList,,buildPhases:buildActionMask:2147483647,displayName:Headers,files:|,|,isa:PBXHeadersBuildPhase,runOnlyForDeploymentPostprocessing:0,,buildActionMask:2147483647,displayName:[CP-User] Generate Specs,files:,inputPaths:|,isa:PBXShellScriptBuildPhase,name:[CP-User] Generate Specs,outputPaths:|,|,|,runOnlyForDeploymentPostprocessing:0,shellPath:/bin/sh,shellScript:set -o pipefail

bash -l -c 'SRCS_DIR=/Users/bonnieandcloud/Documents/Bonnie and cloud/seducia-app/node_modules/react-native/scripts/../Libraries CODEGEN_MODULES_OUTPUT_DIR=/Users/bonnieandcloud/Documents/Bonnie and cloud/seducia-app/node_modules/react-native/s ....
```

I have also a warning from git with 5000 changes on my fork. (node_module is on gitignore)

```
The git repository at '/Users/bonnieandcloud/Documents/Bonnie and cloud/seducia-app' has too many active changes, only a subset of Git features will be enabled.
```

When I want to launch my app on iOS, I have this error:

```
The following build commands failed:
        PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs /Users/bonnieandcloud/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Instadating-ftmtnrbphxvixecideesgbxvywle/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec.build/Script-662957B5B8F4CAAF910F853792BE2D71.sh
(1 failure)
```

Like I said, the project works very well when I don't git clone... I've been stuck for two days.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PhaseScriptExecution \[CP-User\] error in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66742033/phasescriptexecution-cp-user-error-in-react-native)

Answer (score 0):

Download a clean copy of the project and inside of it do: `pod install --repo-update`

Make sure XCode is closed during all that.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I by mistake removed these lines due to which I was getting error. Putting it back fixed the issue